# Replace all list elements based of other list elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list_a

```
list_a = ['some phrase austria', 'another slovakia', 'three paris', 'four united arab emirates']
```

Then I have a list of countries

```
countries = ['aruba', 'afghanistan', 'angola', 'austria', 'åland islands', 'albania', 'andorra', 'united arab emirates', 'argentina', 'armenia', 'american samoa', 'antarctica', 'slovakia', 'antigua and barbuda', 'australia']
```

I want to check if any of the items from countries list exist in every string in list_a and then remove that substring(country name) or replace it with ''.

So the correct output should look like this:

```
final_list = ['some phrase', 'another', 'three paris', 'four'] # since paris is not in the countries list
```

**I tried with the following:**

```
matching = [s for s in list_a if any(xs in s for xs in countries)]
print(matching)
```

So I have now a list of two maching items:

```
['some phrase austria', 'another slovakia', 'four united arab emirates']
```

And I am stuck here but I guess the solution is close.

Comment: I edited a sample_list to cover more scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly there. Try:

```
final_list = [s.split( )[0] if any(xs in s for xs in countries) else s for s in list_a]
print(final_list)
['one', 'two', 'three paris']
```

Comment: could be optimized (maybe a little bit) by doing `s.split(maxsplit=1)[0]` instead.

Comment: ouroboros1 - I just edited a sample list because your solution works fine when we have 2 words items, but with 3 or more not. Very sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are just space-separated words with no punctuation, it would be easiest to `split()` those string, filter out all words that are in the `countries` list, and then `" ".join` them back together.

```
>>> [' '.join(w for w in s.split() if w not in countries) for s in list_a]
['some phrase', 'another', 'three paris']
```

If performance is an issue, you might want to convert `countries` to a `set` first to speed up the lookup. If there is punctuation, you might instead construct a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) from the countries, in the form `\b(c1|c2|...|cn)\b` and replace those with the empty string.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = r"\b(" + "|".join(countries) + r")\b"
>>> [re.sub(p, "", w) for w in list_a]
['some phrase ', 'another ', 'three paris']
```

This method might leave some trailing or double spaces in the strings, though, that would need replacing in a second step.

Comment: didnt noticed the last list elemnt which I added. And I guess this covers it with rstrip() attached 

```
[re.sub(p, "", w).rstrip() for w in list_a]
```